# Performance and usage testing

Tags: java, android, performance, system

I'm about to finish my app, how do i check now, what part of the app uses how many system-resources, and what is blocking when a.s.o. I am looking for something like a head to feet diagnostic like at the doctor or just simpler, any possibility to check-through my app.

Comment: debug your code and use DDMS

Comment: if your environment is Eclipse you will get DDMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the  Dalvik Debug Monitor Server (DDMS). It has memory and thread monitoring capabilities and lots of other useful features. http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html

This is a built-in feature in the Eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly you are looking for is **[Robotium](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/)**.

Robotium is a test framework created to make it easy to write powerful and robust automatic black-box test cases for Android applications. With the support of Robotium, test case developers can write function, system and acceptance test scenarios, spanning multiple Android activities.